# Parse iwlist command output of wireless survey with sed and regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, parsing, sed

I have this command  that I found googling but I need the mac address in the output

```
iwlist ath0 scan | sed -ne 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Quality=\|Encryption key:\|ESSID:\)#\1#p' -e 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Mode:.*\)$#\1\n#p'


Output
ESSID:"Banban"
Quality=18/94  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm
Encryption key:on
```

There is any way to get the mac address too? the Field appears as Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00

Raw Output od the command iwlist ath0 scan

```
  ath0      Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: DC:9F:DB:90:AB:24
                ESSID:"Banban"
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:5.57 GHz (Channel 114)
                Quality=18/94  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Extra:bcn_int=100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Extra:wme_ie=dd180050f2020101850003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00
                Extra:ath_ie=dd0900037f01010000ff7f
                Extra:ubnt_ie=dd0e00156d0000000102b5e102021200
                Extra:htcap_ie=cc011bffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                Extra:mtik_ie=dd26000c42000000011e000000001f660902ff0f41502d4d4f4d454e544f2d320000000000000000
      Cell 02 - Address: DC:9F:DB:08:49:43
```

Comment: There are two Addresses in your raw output and none of them matches what you have asked in your question.

Comment: "How do I do X with Y?" is, generally, a bad way to ask a question -- Y may not be the best way to do X.

Comment: Surely there is a better way to get this info than parsing command output. It looks like iwlist is using the old ioctl interface. There must be something newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` with `-E` (to enable ERE) and `--only-matching` options to get the desired output.

```
iwlist ath0 scan | grep -oE '(ESSID:|Address:|Quality=|Encryption key:).*'
Address: DC:9F:DB:90:AB:24
ESSID:"Banban"
Quality=18/94  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm
Encryption key:on
Address: DC:9F:DB:08:49:43
```

You can even use `grep`'s default RE which is BRE though it might not be as readable:

```
iwlist ath0 scan | grep -o '\(ESSID:\|Address:\|Quality=\|Encryption key:\).*'
Address: DC:9F:DB:90:AB:24
ESSID:"Banban"
Quality=18/94  Signal level=-78 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm
Encryption key:on
Address: DC:9F:DB:08:49:43
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very valid point. The `-P` option was completely unnecessary. Have updated the solution. Thanks for the feedback. Appreciate it as always.

Comment: @MichaelJaros Correct, it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 'awk' expression:

```
iwlist ath0 scan | awk '/Quality|ESSID|Encryption key|Address/ { print $0 }'
```

As jaypal has already pointed out, there are two hardware addresses in your output. Both will be matched. The output will include leading whitespace (good for humans, bad for scripts). If you do not like that, use

```
iwlist ath0 scan | awk '/Quality|ESSID|Encryption key|Address/ { gsub(/^[ ]+/,"") ; print $0 }'
```

instead.

Comment: ...though stripping leading whitespace could certainly also be done in awk.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, extend the original command as follows:

```
 iwlist ath0 scan | sed \
   -ne 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Quality=\|Encryption key:\|ESSID:\)#\1#p' \
   -e 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Mode:.*\)$#\1\n#p' \
   -ne 's#^.*\(Address: \)#\1#p'
```

As pointed out by Charles Duffy, when using GNU sed (e.g. on Linux), the syntax can be simplified as follows (using the `-r` option to enable Extended Regular Expressions):

```
 iwlist ath0 scan | sed -r \
   -ne 's#^[[:space:]]*(Quality=|Encryption key:|ESSID:)#\1#p' \
   -e 's#^[[:space:]]*(Mode:.*)$#\1\n#p' \
   -ne 's#^.*(Address: )#\1#p'
```

Comment: +1. However, being able to write `\|` in BRE to get behavior equivalent to the ERE `|` syntax is a GNU extension, and if you're going to use GNU extensions, why not just use `sed -r` and get proper ERE (and not need the backslashes around `|`, `(` and `)` at all)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used the same syntax as the OP's command, merely extending the command to fulfil the requirement. That said, fully agree with your comment :)

Comment: The command iwlist ath0 scan | awk '/Quality|ESSID|Encryption key|Address/ { gsub(/^[ ]+/,"") ; print $0 }' works great also short the other command also works  I going to try send this command froma .net app to how it works, thanks all.